# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "sacar/pelar el cobre"?

Tags: historia, locuciones

Al menos en Colombia *sacar* o *pelar el cobre* se usa cuando alguien ha simulado ser de una manera pero luego muestra su verdadera forma de ser (generalmente algo negativo).

Una de las acepciones de cobre en el DLE habla de la expresión "vérsele a alguien el cobre", que tiene la misma idea aunque entiendo que se refiere más a cuando se descubren las intenciones del otro en lugar de cuando dicha persona por sí misma muestra su lado verdadero:

> [**vérsele a alguien el cobre**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Xwcm0Q#0yHbmuQ)
>
> 1. *loc. verb. coloq*. vérsele el plumero.

Y para "vérsele el plumero":

> [**vérsele a alguien el plumero**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TQrFXa5)
>
> 1. *loc. verb. coloq*. Descubrirse sus intenciones o defectos.

¿Por qué tiene el cobre una connotación negativa en este caso? ¿Por qué lo tiene "plumero"? ¿Está relacionado "cobre" con "plumero"?

Comment: No creo que "cobre" y "plumero" tengan relación, son simplemente dos locuciones que han venido a significar lo mismo, y la RAE redirige de una a otra para no duplicar definiciones.

Comment: Origen de la expresión "**vérsele a alguien el plumero**" : https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-procede-la-expresion-se-te-ve-el-plumero/

Comment: Por cierto, en el DLE de 1970 se define "vérsele a uno el cobre" como "descubrir, o mostrar, alguien la hilaza" o "hilacha", que significa "dejar ver sus intenciones o defectos", que es más parecido a la expresión que comentas de "sacar" o "pelar el cobre", ya que se puede usar como "Fulano ha mostrado su hilacha".

Comment: Y en México es "enseñar el cobre". A mi se me ocurre que puede ser como si tuvieras una aleación o algo que piensas que está hecho de oro (casi) puro, pero rascas un poco y te das cuenta de que es falso: hay mucho cobre bajo una fina capa de oro para engañarte.

Comment: El origen que yo conozco es el que comenta @Diego. Las joyas baratas eran hechas de cobre y bañadas en oro o plata. Con el tiempo se "pelaban"y **mostraban el cobre**

Comment: Copio el motivo de la recompensa, pues si no se pierde al terminar: _La respuesta actual solo explica el uso de "sacar el cobre", no dice nada sobre "pelar el cobre". Se menciona en algún comentario pero estaría bien que una respuesta lo abordase. Y, de paso, que explique el uso que se hace de la frase aquí: http://twitter.com/ELTIEMPO/status/1009127096717860865 "¡Colombiano en Rusia, no peles el cobre!"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como están definidas las expresiones "vérsele a alguien el cobre" o "vérsele el plumero", no creo que la connotación sea obligatoriamente negativa. La definición de la segunda dice "descubrirse sus intenciones o defectos". Vale que "defectos" pueda ser negativo, pero una intención oculta no tiene por qué ser necesariamente mala (aunque hay muchas probabilidades de que lo sea). En todo caso, no es que el cobre o un plumero tengan *per se* connotaciones negativas, sino que esta viene dada por la forma en que se originaron las expresiones (que no creo que tengan nada que ver, simplemente el DLE usa la segunda para definir la primera).

Hablando ya de sus orígenes, en los comentarios ya se apuntan. Para la versión del cobre bien puede tener su origen en las joyas baratas hechas de cobre y recubiertas por una película que les dé apariencia de oro, que con el tiempo se pelaban y mostraban su verdadero origen, aunque [la explicación de @alexchvrches](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23298/12637) también parece plausible. Para la versión del plumero, se explica [aquí](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-procede-la-expresion-se-te-ve-el-plumero/):

> El origen de la locución [...] se remonta a la época de las Cortes de Cádiz de 1812, en la que se reconoció y reguló a las milicias nacionales; una fuerza compuesta por voluntarios dispuestos a defender los ideales progresistas. Por su parte, el bando absolutista no era partidario de dicho cuerpo.

La Milicia Nacional se vestía con gorros coronados por penachos de plumas que destacaban en la lejanía, "pudiéndose distinguir y saber a qué bando y cuerpo pertenecían sus portadores".

> El origen de la expresión comenzó a utilizarse cuando en tertulias y/o debates políticos entre conservadores y progresistas, en un momento de la discusión se les decía a éstos últimos "a mí no me engañas, que te he visto el plumero", en clara referencia al penacho de plumas del gorro.

En cuanto a la expresión "pelar el cobre", aunque de origen similar parece que su significado es ligeramente diferente. [Según el DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pelar):

> **pelar el cobre**. loc. verb. *Ni, Co.* Mostrar *alguien* un lado negativo o de mala intención ante una situación.

La expresión se usa en Colombia, por lo que [el texto mencionado por @walen](https://twitter.com/ELTIEMPO/status/1009127096717860865):

> ¡Colombiano en Rusia, no peles el cobre!

significaría que no por estar fuera de tu país debes mostrar tu peor cara, sino comportarte con la misma educación como si estuvieras en tu casa.

Answer (score 5):

En México, se cuenta sobre cómo al momento de una comida con invitados, si el anfitrión era hipócrita o no eras de su agrado, utilizaban **vajilla de cobre** en dicha comida, esta era una falta de respeto para la persona que era la invitada. Lo correcto era utilizar vajilla de porcelana o plata. De ahí que se utilice la frase "**sacar el cobre**" para hacer referencia a que **una persona muestra su verdadera forma de ser**.